# Check if given string can be created by a set of characters cut out from magazine article

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

"Observe that when you cut a character out of a magazine, the character on the reverse side of the page is also removed. Give an algorithm to determine whether you can generate a given string by pasting cutouts from a given magazine. Assume that you are given a function that will identify the character and its position on the reverse side of the page for any given character position."

How can I do it?

I can do some initial pruning so that if a needed character has only one way of getting picked up, its taken initially before turning the sub-problem for dynamic technique, but what after this initial pruning?

What is the time and space complexity?

Comment: My guess would be, that you could somehow reduce this to Mincut/Maxflow, but I am not yet sure how to do it. Something along the lines of using the combinations of characters as a links in the graph and the string as flow. I'll have to think more closely about this later this evening.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As @LiKao suggested, this can be solved using max flow. To construct the network we make two "layers" of vertices: one with all the distinct characters in the input string and one with each position on the page. Make an edge with capacity 1 from a character to a position if that position has that character on one side. Make edges of capacity 1 from each position to the sink, and make edges from the source to each character with capacity equal to the multiplicity of that character in the input string.

For example, let's say we're searching for the word "FOO" on a page with four positions:

```
pos    1 2 3 4
front  F C O Z
back   O O K Z
```

We then generate the following network, ignoring position 4 since it does not provide any of the required characters.

[image: the generated network]

Now, we only need to determine if there is a flow from the source to the sink of `length("FOO") = 3` or more.

Comment: Is this solution related to solving the assignment algorithm via max flow?

Comment: @mcdowella: Yes. This is solving the problem of assigning positions on the page to characters in the input string.

Comment: I even don't understand the question. So it means you are given a string S, then you do cuttings and each cut can give you two chars. put all the chars you cut together, see whether those chars can equals to S? Could you please help clarify this question? @hammer

Comment: @Jack: You can ignore the cutting. Basically, you have a bunch of pieces of paper with a single letter on each side. In the original question they came from a magazine, but they could come from anywhere. You then have to determine whether you can arrange those pieces of paper to form some target word S.

Comment: Any rules for forming the word? According to your explanation, If I have 3 pieces of paper, each paper has two chars (double sided), then I have totally 6 char, then is the target to order these 6 chars to a given word?

Comment: @Jack: No, the whole point is that you can only use each piece once, but you can choose what order you want them in and which side you want to use from each piece.

Comment: ahhh, ok. So in my example, anyway, I just get 3 chars and each from either side of one piece. Can I just use a simple backtrack to try them all out?

Comment: @Jack: Sure, but the algorithm I've described is more efficient.

Comment: I also think max-flow is the right way to solve this exercise, however, in Skiena's book this exercise is listed in the Dynamic Programming section. Could it be that there is a space-and-time-efficient solution using dynamic programming?

Comment: @axel22 Were you able to come up with a DP solution for this problem? I've formulated one, but don't see any benefits over brute-force search. Let `S` be the sequence of letters from the cutout, and `X` be the string to be generated. String ending in position `j` may be generated using `1..i` letters (`S[0..i]`). `dp[i][j] = (dp[i-1][j-1] && (S[i]_f == X[j] || S[i]_r == X[j])) || dp[i-1][j] if i > 0, j > 0`, base conditions not shown.

Comment: We also need to be careful which pair of letters we choose when there are multiple matches. For example, given `{(F,O), (F,C), (O,K), (Z,Z)}` and string `FOO`, if we choose `(F,O)` first, we won't get a match. If, however, we choose `(F,C)` first, we will get a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming directly.

We are given string s with n letters. We are given a set of pieces P = {p_1, ..., p_k}. Each piece has one letter in the front p_i.f and one in the back p_i.b.

Denote with f(j, p) the function that returns true if it is feasible to create substring s_1...s_j using pieces in p \subseteq P, and false otherwise.

The following recurrence holds:
f(n, P) = f(n-1, P-p_1) | f(n-1, P-p_2) | ... | f(n-1, P-p_k)

In plain English the feasibility of s using all pieces in P, depends on the feasibility of the substring s_1...s_n-1 given one less piece, and we try removing all possible pieces (of course in practice we do not have to remove all pieces one by one; we only need to remove those pieces for which p_i.f == s_n || p_i.b == s_n).

The initial condition is that f(1, P-p_1) = f(1, P-p2) = ... = true, assuming that we have already checked a-priori (in linear time) that there are enough letters in P to cover all the letters in s.

Comment: There are exponentially many subsets of `P`, so for some inputs dynamic programming might not work here, seems to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This will end up checking all possible subsets in the worst case. In addition, the recurrence relation is not correctly formulated either.

Answer (score 0):

While this problem can be formulated as a Maxflow problem as shown in the accepted answer, it is simpler and more efficient to formulate it as a maximum cardinality matching problem in a bipartite graph. Maxflow algorithms like [Dinic's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) are slower than the special case algorithms like [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

The bipartite graph is formed by adding two edges from every character of the given string to a cutout, one edge for each side. We then run Hopcroft–Karp. In the end, we simply check whether the cardinality of the matching is equal to the length of the string.

For a working implementation (in Scala) using [JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/), see my [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/adm/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/asarkar/adm/dp/package.scala#L152).

I'd like to come up with a more efficient DP solution, since Skiena's book has this problem in the DP section, but so far haven't found any.